# VBA Converting a String y=f(x1,x2...) formula to Double?

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, I don't know if it's possible to do in VBA or not but I've spend almost four hours researching with no luck.
I'm doing a project with Excel VBA to make a macro that can calculate any *y=f(x)* function that contains multiple *x*-variables that the user can type in the InputBox as such;

[image: InputBox]

Basically by defining the input as String, I could get it printed out in any cell in the worksheet with no problem.

```
Dim f As String
f = InputBox(Prompt:="Please input your function" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & 
Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "y =")
Cells(1,1) = "y = " + f
```

Now the problem is, I want to use this *y=f(x1,x2...)* that the user has typed into the InputBox to define a variable *y* as a function of *x* as you normally would do in VBA. However, the variables will be some *n*-dimensional vectors of random numbers so they'll have to be defined as such, for example;

```
Dim x1() As Double, x2() As Double, x3() As Double
Dim y() As Double, n As Long
... Randomize and defining x variables ...

ReDim y(1 To n, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To n
y(i,1)=x1(i,1) + x2(i,1) + x3(i,1)
Next i
```

Here, the expected value of *x*'s and *n* are to be determined by the user itself in a separate Input Box.

Now instead of typing *y(i,1)=x1(i,1) + x2(i,1) + x3(i,1)* by myself in the Module, I want the program to be able to read and define *y* from the user inputted formula so if the user changes the *y=f(x)*, the program will automatically change its *y* formula as well, thus it'll be able to calculate various formulas without the user having to open the Module and changes it from within.

Please tell me if it's possible or might be too complicated, I'll appreciate any input you guys could give me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than **y=f(x1,x2)**, simply put together the user-determined string-formula like **=f(x1,x2)** and either put it in a cell or `Evaluate()` it directly.  Like **y=Evaluate(user-string)**.  Where **y** is a VBA variable that you have already `Dim`ed in your code.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Evaluate() has gotten me to the right direction, I was able to extract the f(x1,x2) from the String in a cell and using Replace() to replace the "x1" and "x2" with defined values of the respective variables. It finally printed out a value as a result from the equation!

However, I'm not quite done yet because I have n-dimensional vector, so to say the variables are x1(n) and x2(n). Simply replacing the "x" with x(n) didn't work because the formula String obviously isn't a vector, but I'm still trying.